# Adapter Pattern with different abilities for each adaptee

Tags: design-patterns, adapter

I am writing a program that will make use of the adapter pattern for a handful of APIs. The goal is to be able to combine and aggregate data from each API. The problem is, not every API has the same functionality. For example:

**API A**

- List all markets
- List specific market price
- List orders

**API B**

- List specific market price
- List market 24hr high/low

Notice how API B is able to get the 24hr price highs and lows, but API A cannot. Meanwhile, API A can list all markets available, while API B cannot.

What is the ideal way to approach a scenario like this?

- I have thought about having a FLAGS enum that lists each API's functionalities, but that feels like a roundabout way of doing things and requires a lot of additional code for checking and whatnot.
- I have considered separate adapters for each ability that the API can handle, but that could require a great deal of inheritance to the point where each API was using 5+ interfaces for the actions alone.

My goal is to make the program easily extendable to other APIs in the future. If this is my goal, how should I approach this? (I am using C# if that matters)

Comment: Do API A and API B have some common functionalities and one of them has some more than the other or they are totally and completely different.

Comment: @msoliman The APIs are all from different services, and the goal is to parse the received data so that it is always in the same format. There will always be "common" functionality in the sense that some of it will produce the same result after being parsed (e.g. Get a specified market's current volume and price). However, each API tends to have its own unique set of functions as well (e.g. one API is able to retrieve account balances and real-time order lists while others cannot)

Comment: I would recommend separate __Adapter__ for each __Adaptee__. Adapter's purpose is just to match the __provided interface to required interface__ and it is generally a patch (name itself suggests) when we do not have control over the provided interface (API). I am assuming your  Adaptees are not interchangeable, as their provided interfaces are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slim interfaces are your friend here.

Using your examples:

```
public interface IListAllMarkets
{
    List<Market> GetAllMarkets();
}
public interface IListMarketPrice
{
    List<MarketPrice> GetMarketPrices();
}
public interface IListOrders
{
    List<Order> GetOrders();
}
public interface IHighLow
{
    List<HighLow> GetHighLows();
}

// then the class that handles the apis

public class MyReusableClass :  IListAllMarkets, 
                                IListMarketPrice, 
                                IListOrders, 
                                IHighLow
{
    private readonly ApiA _apiA = new ApiA();
    private readonly ApiB _apiB = new ApiB();

    public List<Market> GetAllMarkets()
    {
        return _apiA.ListAllMarkets() ;
    }

    public List<MarketPrice> GetMarketPrices()
    {
        // pretending that the business logic is try apiA first then fallback to apiB
        var prices = _apiA.ListSpecificMarketPrices();
        if (prices.Count == 0)
        {
            prices = _apiB.ListSpecificMarketPrices();
        }
        return prices;
    }

    public List<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        return _apiA.ListAllOrders();
    }

    public List<HighLow> GetHighLows()
    {
        return _apiB.ListMarket24HourJHighsLows();
    }
}
```

Now that we got the code out of the way, I would suggest that we avoid approaching things in a "How can I use this pattern to solve X?", instead approach things from a perspective of "I have this problem X? How can I solve X? Is there a pattern that can help me solve it?"